# Lerna watch not detecting changes on oracle linux machine

Tags: reactjs, lerna, nomachine-nx

We are having a mono repo react app and trying to integrate lerna into it.

Environment details

1. OS - Oracle Linux OS
2. Node version - 16.8.1
3. React version - 17.0.1
4. Lerna version - 7.1.1

While running lerna watch command , its not detecting changes to our js files in this environment. Note It is working fine in windows machine running on node v18.16.1.

Executing below command

```
npx -c 'lerna watch -- echo \$LERNA_PACKAGE_NAME \$LERNA_FILE_CHANGES'
```

Below is the output. After that whenever we do any changes lerna is not detecting these changes.

npx -c 'lerna watch --verbose -- echo $LERNA_PACKAGE_NAME $LERNA_FILE_CHANGES'

lerna notice cli v7.1.3
lerna verb packageConfigs Resolving packages based on package.json "workspaces" configuration.
lerna verb rootPath /home/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
lerna info watch Executing command "echo $LERNA_PACKAGE_NAME $LERNA_FILE_CHANGES" on changes in 5 packages.

> NX   running with args: {"command":"echo $LERNA_PACKAGE_NAME $LERNA_FILE_CHANGES","projectNameEnvName":"LERNA_PACKAGE_NAME","fileChangesEnvName":"LERNA_FILE_CHANGES","includeDependentProjects":false,"projects":["XXXXXX","XXXXXX","XXXXXX","XXXXXX","XXXXXX"],"verbose":true}

> NX   starting watch process

> NX   watch process waiting...

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.